# Fancybox - form submit and close it?

Tags: javascript, fancybox

**I start my fancybox like code down**

```
$('a.detail').click(function() {
   $.fancybox({
         'width'         : 750,
         'height'        : 520,
         'title'         : 'EDIÇÃO DE SHOW',
   'titlePosition' : 'inside',
   'transitionIn' : 'fade',
   'transitionOut' : 'none',
   'href'          : 'templates/detail.php?id=<?php echo $tg_id['id'];?>',
   'type'          : 'iframe'  
   })
  })
```

and into myfancy, I got a form to update informations about schedules.

```
$(function() {

   $("form#comment").submit(function() {

   var dat = $("#datepicker").val();
   var uf = $("#uf").val();
   var flr = $("input[name='flpic']:checked").val();
   var tit = $("#titulo").val();
   var mssg = $("#mensagem").val();
   var id = $("#id").val();

   if(BrowserDetect.browser == 'Explorer'){
    var nav = 'ie'
   } else {
    var nav = 'ot'
   }

   $.ajax({

             type: "POST",
             url: "edit_agenda.php",
             data: "id="+id+"&datepicker="+ dat+"&uf="+uf+"&fl="+flr+"&titulo="+tit+"&mensagem="+mssg+"&bro="+nav,
             success: function(){

      $("#status").html("<img src='../images/1-0.gif' alt='Enviando' />");

   **???? Can I call some function to close this fancy here?**   

              }

         });

      return false;

  });

 });
```

My question is:

After submit this form, can I close this fancy within a function?

Comment: How is it that this is working correctly? Fancybox does not display automatically when you call .fancybox, so I feel like you must have some other code that you're not showing?

Answer (score 2):

You can close it with `$.fancybox.close()`. Mind reading [the API](http://fancybox.net/api).

Comment: The point is, my fancybox doesn´t close. Becouse it is inside a iframe.

Comment: "Within an iframe use - parent.$.fancybox.close();"

Answer (score 2):

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "edit_agenda.php",
    data: "id="+id+"&datepicker="+ dat+"&uf="+uf+"&fl="+flr+"&titulo="+tit+"&mensagem="+mssg+"&bro="+nav,
    success: function(){
    parent.$.fancybox.close();
    }
});
```

Comment: Can you add a description as to how this code addresses the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Within an iframe

```
<input name="submit" type="submit" value="close" onClick="$.fancybox.close();" />
```

will also work.

Answer (score 0):

Use `parent.$.fancybox.close();` within the Iframe.

Answer (score 0):

use this below script:

```
parent.jQuery.fancybox.close();
```

Answer (score -1):

Try a PHP solution could try a simple rewrite in javascript if you want.

```
<?php
$close = 1;
if( $close) { echo ' <body onunload="self.close()"> ' ;} 
?>
```