# Calling Fancybox from within .click()

Tags: jquery, fancybox

Hi I have seen example code that makes no sense to me. On this stack Question at [Fancybox - form submit and close it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4758964/fancybox-form-submit-and-close-it) the user has posted this code:

```
$('a.detail').click(function() {
   $.fancybox({
         'width'         : 750,
         'height'        : 520,
         'title'         : 'EDIÇÃO DE SHOW',
   'titlePosition' : 'inside',
   'transitionIn' : 'fade',
   'transitionOut' : 'none',
   'href'          : 'templates/detail.php?id=<?php echo $tg_id['id'];?>',
   'type'          : 'iframe'  
   })
  })
```

but fancybox doesn't seem to behave this way. The fancybox call seems to only load the trigger onto the link, not actually display it. I would really like to know how to do it this way without having to wrap a hidden link into the page and trigger it that way. This seems alot cleaner.

Comment: What do you actualy want to do?

Comment: It would be fantastic if there was a way to reliably call Fancybox with a simple jQuery command. In the end I believe I called the Fancybox command twice which seems to work fine in Firefox, IE, Chrome, and Safari although in Mobile Safari the user must doubleclick the element to open the Fancybox.

Answer (score 1):

if are using zend and php  then create and separate action and view  to load the content or site u want to display . and disable the layout ..

Answer (score 0):

What about calling fancybox directly like that:

```
$.fancybox(things_to_be_displayed, {settings});
```

You can use this call in any event handler. Check the manual call examples on fancybox webpage.